# How to get data from sqllite db in my model?

Tags: c#

Hi I want to ask how can I access my data from sqllite in my model (User).

I have method like this

```
Class Person
public void getPersonById(int id)
{
    //Todo: access and get data from db here    
}
```

Here is my connection class - I tried that I connect to my db so I just have to use  it in my model

```
    class Connection
    {
        string sqlLiteDatabaseName = @"URI=file:C:\Users\Admin\Code\Covid\Covid\CovidDatabase.sqlite3";
        SQLiteConnection conn { get; }

        public Connection()
        {
            try
            {
                this.conn = new SQLiteConnection(this.sqlLiteDatabaseName);
            }
            catch(SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }
        }
}
```

I am new in C# so maybe it is obvious but I don´t really know how to do this. Thx for help anyway.

### My database structure of user  is like this
Table - user

Id - int
Name - string
Surname - string

Comment: Personally, I use [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) with [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) that allows to use strongly typed DataSets and all RAD Designers of VS. This is the one I have found that works the best being open source. You can learn ADO.NET with the unique and awesome book [Beginning C # 2005 Databases](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Beginning+C%23+2005+Databases-p-9780470044063) for example. There are several free and commercial [SQLite ADO.NET providers](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) available around the world.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I added table structure  and model is Related db